# How to get a bracket that looks like this?

Tags: brackets

I'm trying to get a bracket that looks like this :

[image]

I tried

```
$4\tan^2\left(\dfrac{x}{3}\right)$
```

But got this instead :

[image]

Comment: Use a font with narrow brackets.

Comment: that kind of parentheses do not look nice, they are too big ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remaining within Computer Modern fonts, the characters called, respectively, `\lgroup` and `\rgroup` get pretty close to what you ask, although they don’t look quite the same.  The `mleftright` package fixes the space around `\left` and `\right` delimiters.

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{mleftright}



\begin{document}

See \textsl{The \TeX book}, p.~150:
\[ 4\tan^{2} \mleft\lgroup \frac{x}{3} \mright\rgroup \]

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image: Output of the code]

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use this kind of braces ...
However, use `\lgroup` and `\rgroup`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\delimitershortfall=-1pt % make it larger
\begin{document}

    $ 4\tan^{2} \left\lgroup\dfrac{x}{3}\right\rgroup$

\end{document}
```

[image]